# Refresh parent page on close of lightning quick action modal

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-events, quickaction

I have a custom lightning component which pops up when I click on a quick action in a record detail page.

Once I click on a button in the popup, I want the popup to close and the parent detail page to refresh.

I use `$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire()`
to close the popup. But I am not being able to refresh the parent detail page.

Is that possible?

Comment: please reach out to the CM Team to have your duplicate account merged. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try [force:refreshView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_refreshView.htm), which reloads all data for the view. So in addition to `$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();` add `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();` in your setCallback method.

```
({
    handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        var saveLeadAction = component.get("c.leadSave");
        saveLeadAction.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
                $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();

            }else if (res.getState() === "ERROR") {
                console.log("Errore Saving Contact ");
            } 
        }); 
        $A.enqueueAction(saveLeadAction);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank You! I was trying to use `refreshView` before `closeQuickAction` (makes more sense to me - how can closed component fire another event?), but that did not work.

Comment: @saroj, Component is not refreshed with refreshView, seems like view is refreshed but component are not refreshed is there any workaround on this.

Comment: @sarveshkumar What do you mean by component are not refreshed?